# Android Studio - auto generate builder class setters

Tags: android-studio, code-completion, auto-generate

If you hit the Generate shortkey in Android studio you get some options to auto generate code like setters and getters. I would like the option to generate setters in the form of a Builder class. meaning that every set method returns the object on which it was called.

```
class BlaBla{

    int var1, var2;

    public BlaBla setVar1(int var1){
        this.var1 = var1;
        return this;
    }
    public BlaBla setVar2(int var2){
        this.var2 = var2;
        return this;
    }

}
```

So now I can do this:

```
BlaBla bla = new BlaBla();
bla.setVar1(5).setVar2(6);
```

However I can't find any plugin for this functionality. Any directions would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: I found this: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6585-builder-generator. It's not the best plugin in the world but it's the closest thing i ve found.